# R : Finding minimum value in a matrix

Tags: r, matrix, sum

I want to iteratively sum the minimum value across different rows.

I have a matrix:

[image]

I would like to find the minimum value of this matrix by starting at row 1 (selected value not 0). Then iteratively, selecting the column that provides minimum value in row 1. Next, choose next row number which is the same number as the previously selected column and so on. Finally, sum the total numbers.

For example, start at row 1 and select column 4 because it provides the minimum value as 13.924. Then, moving to row 4 and finding the min value again which could be column 3 as 46.789. Then, moving to row 3 and finding the min value in this row which is in column 2 as 71.950. Then, from row 2, column 5 is selected.

For this example:

```
mat_test[1,4] + mat_test[4,3] + mat_test[3,2] + mat_test[2,1]

13.924 + 46.789 + 71.950 + 25.579

total sum = 158.242
```

Comment: When should the loop stop? When it eventually gets to a particular point in the matrix? And what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your matrix `mat_test` is always a square matrix, you may try the code below for your objective

```
mat_test <- `diag<-`(mat_test,Inf)
inds <- c()
row <- 1
while (!row %in% inds[,1]) {
  inds <- rbind(inds,c(row,rowNew <- which.min(mat_test[row,])))
  row <- rowNew
}
total <- sum(mat_test[inds])
```

Example

```
set.seed(1)
mat_test <- `diag<-`(matrix(rnorm(25),nrow = 5),0)

> mat_test
           [,1]       [,2]       [,3]        [,4]        [,5]
[1,]        Inf -0.8204684  1.5117812 -0.04493361  0.91897737
[2,]  0.1836433        Inf  0.3898432 -0.01619026  0.78213630
[3,] -0.8356286  0.7383247        Inf  0.94383621  0.07456498
[4,]  1.5952808  0.5757814 -2.2146999         Inf -1.98935170
[5,]  0.3295078 -0.3053884  1.1249309  0.59390132         Inf
```

then

```
> inds
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    2
[2,]    2    4
[3,]    4    3
[4,]    3    1
```

and

```
> mat_test[inds]
[1] -0.82046838 -0.01619026 -2.21469989 -0.83562861
```